# Node js app is getting an error after deploying it to heroku.com server

Tags: node.js, heroku, wit.ai

My name si Alin Stanescu and am currently working on a bachelor project using wit.ai.

I have created a Node.js app which is using the wit.ai node_module and some other modules.
The thing is that everything is working fine on my local mashie but when I am deploying it on herokus's server, the app is crashing.
After an exchange of email with the customer service from heroku, they suggested that I should better contact you and let you know about this problem because they think you guys may fix this.

I will attach you the errors that I am getting now on their server and if you need more information I can provide it.

### Thank you.

Application Logs

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041822+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Interface.write (readline.js:334:49)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041836+00:00 app[web.1]:     at prompt (/app/node_modules/node-wit/lib/interactive.js:18:8)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041837+00:00 app[web.1]:     at module.exports (/app/node_modules/node-wit/lib/interactive.js:20:3)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041837+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object. (/app/wit.js:61:1)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041838+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041838+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041840+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041839+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:473:32)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.133177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2016-10-17T12:26:50.920992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-dawn-22923.herokuapp.com request_id=ef851c74-b288-4991-8341-26a399f1b5fd fwd="83.95.189.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-10-17T12:26:52.098587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-dawn-22923.herokuapp.com request_id=8f6fb2fb-0f17-4213-a265-188ce11862ab fwd="83.95.189.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041822+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Interface.write (readline.js:334:49)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041836+00:00 app[web.1]:     at prompt (/app/node_modules/node-wit/lib/interactive.js:18:8)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041837+00:00 app[web.1]:     at module.exports (/app/node_modules/node-wit/lib/interactive.js:20:3)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041837+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object. (/app/wit.js:61:1)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041838+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041838+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041840+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.041839+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:473:32)

2016-10-17T09:54:23.133177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2016-10-17T12:26:50.920992+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fathomless-dawn-22923.herokuapp.com request_id=ef851c74-b288-4991-8341-26a399f1b5fd fwd="83.95.189.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

2016-10-17T12:26:52.098587+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fathomless-dawn-22923.herokuapp.com request_id=8f6fb2fb-0f17-4213-a265-188ce11862ab fwd="83.95.189.221" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Seeing your source code would help, specifically what's going on in and around line 61 of /app/wit.js

Comment: Hi Paul, I can send you the whole wit.js file to take a look at it. Just let me know how should I do it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for pointing me the line number...because after commenting it everything seems to work just fine now.

Comment: Are you getting an error of no cross origin access ?